# FTP connection to Linux Mint: 550 Permission denied. Error: Critical file transfer error

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, ftp, apache-httpd, vsftpd

I am using Linux Mint and Apache on my laptop as my own made web server. I can display the html file if I connect to the IP adress. I can display all files in my hard drive if I connect using FileZilla FTP from my Windows machine but trying to move files to the server gives:

```
Response: 550 Permission denied
Error: Critical file transfer error
```

I checked Nmap on my linuxserver and ports 21, 80, 139 and 445 are open. I've installed vsftpd and set write_enable on at the configuration file. I haven't restarted the server though because if I do I have to install vsftpd from the start due to errors.

I've also given all rights to the www folder that apache uses with sudo chmod -R 777 www command

How can I enable file transmission to my server?

Comment: "Permission denied"? Does the user you're logging in as have persmission to create files in the directory you're trying to move files to?

Comment: I logged in as an administrator so I should? I am a linux beginner so I am not quite sure.